# Minimum code to render master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I created a new blank custom master page in SharePoint designer 2010. Made it the default page and now when I open the website in browser it shows error:

```
Error
An unexpected error has occured
Correlation ID: 44eccc...................
```

What is the minimum code that must be present in master page to make it work? I thought since I am creating it from SPD then it will take care of it but looks like that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good post how to create master pages with minimum generated code: http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/using-a-different-master-page-for-authenticated-users-in-sharepoint/

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of parts that have to be in a master page in order for it to work so it is a better approach to start with either an existing Master Page or a template.  I've used the [Starter Master Pages on CodePlex](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) in several projects and they work out really well as a "blank" starting point.

Just keep in mind that you *really* do not want to change the way that the Ribbon appears as doing so will bite you in any one of a dozen unique ways.